# React: How to keep private methods bound to relative component?

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to use a React component as a utilities class containing methods that will update another (view) component's state.

The problem is, when I bind the utility method to the view component, the private methods that the utility method calls do not seem to be accessible and I get the error `TypeError: this._filterForCurrentlySelectedTimeRange is not a function`.

I have tried:
1. Keeping the private methods in the view component (this works, obviously.)
2. Binding the private methods to the utility component in various ways.

My code currently resembles this:

**utilities.jsx**

```
class ExampleUtilities extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.capitalizeFirstChar = this.privateMethod.bind(this);
    }

    static capitalize(word) {
       const result = this._capitalizeFirstChar(word);
       this.setState({ capitalizedWord: result })
    }

    _capitalizeFirstChar(word) {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    }
}
export default ExampleUtilities;
```

**view.jsx**

```
import ExampleUtilities from '../components/utilities';

class View extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { capitalizedWord: null }
    }

    render() {
        return( 
            <input type="input" onChange={event =>  
    ExampleUtilities.capitalize.bind(this, event.target.value)}</input>
        )
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would be able to keep the private methods inside the utilities class and call them with the utility methods. Is this possible?

Please ask me to clarify if this is not clear; I feel like I've been gnawing on this for a bit and I've lost sight of what makes sense.

Comment: I'm curious why you are extending React.Component for utility functions...

Answer (score 0):

As Ted pointed out, there is no reason for ExampleUtilities to extend `React.Component`. There isn't any reason for it to be a class. I agree with Andy, that calling `setState` in a utility function like this is very odd, though in a few months (if you don't want to use the alpha), you could use hooks to do a stateful utility in a cleaner way.
Below is an example based on your code that shows managing the state in 3 different ways:

- The first (View.js) is most similar to yours using a bound utility method that calls `setState`
- The second (View2.js) uses a simpler utility and keeps the state management in its own component
- The third (HooksView.js) shows how in the alpha version of React you can use a hook to encapsulate this and get rid of all the class boilerplate

Here's the code:

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import View from "./View";
import View2 from "./View2";
import HooksView from "./HooksView";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <View />
      <br />
      <View2 />
      <br />
      <HooksView />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`utilities.js`

```
import { useState } from "react";

// must be bound
export const capitalizeFirstCharAndSetState = function(word) {
  const result = privateCapitalizeFirstChar(word);
  this.setState({ capitalizedWord: result });
};
export const capitalizeFirstChar = word => {
  return privateCapitalizeFirstChar(word);
};
// not exported
const privateCapitalizeFirstChar = word =>
  word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);

export const useCapitalizedChangeHandler = () => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const setCapitalizedWord = event => {
    const capitalized = privateCapitalizeFirstChar(event.target.value);
    setWord(capitalized);
  };
  return [word, setCapitalizedWord];
};
```

`View.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { capitalizeFirstCharAndSetState } from "./utilities";

class View extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { capitalizedWord: "" };
    this.changeHandler1 = capitalizeFirstCharAndSetState.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="input"
        value={this.state.capitalizedWord}
        onChange={event => this.changeHandler1(event.target.value)}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default View;
```

`View2.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { capitalizeFirstChar } from "./utilities";

class View2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { capitalizedWord: "" };
    this.changeHandler2 = event => {
      this.setState({
        capitalizedWord2: capitalizeFirstChar(event.target.value)
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="input"
        value={this.state.capitalizedWord2}
        onChange={this.changeHandler2}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default View2;
```

`HooksView.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useCapitalizedChangeHandler } from "./utilities";

const HooksView = () => {
  const [word, setWord] = useCapitalizedChangeHandler();
  return <input type="input" value={word} onChange={setWord} />;
};
export default HooksView;
```

And here's a CodeSandbox where you can try this out:

[image: Edit pmw8v2184j]

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I am planning to factor out the update to the state in the utility method; I do see why that would be odd. This answer doesn't fully answer my question. If I have a function in another class that binds to the component on which it is used, how do I call or reference other functions within that utility method? The first answer provided removes the private method, which is not what I want to do, and all of the answers provided make use of the utility function being in the same file as the view component.

Comment: Wait if I remove the need to update state in there I don't need to bind to `this` in the other component!

Comment: I kept it in one file for easier pasting. It is now split into multiple files to show that aspect.